# how to change drop down on particulare data select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

In below if condition there are few id (id="store_id") on which i need both master and salve in below drop down option(id="store_machine"). else only master . Am using switch case  where that particular id will come then both thing master and salve should come ,except that only master

```
<tr>
<td>
    <b>Store ID</b>
    <br>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="number"  id="store_id" readonly>
    <br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <b>Machine</b>
    <br>
</td>
<td>
    <select name="select-native-3" id="store_machine" data-iconpos="left">
        <option value="Master">Master</option>
        <option value="Slave">Slave</option>
    </select>
    <br>
</td>
</tr>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#store_id').on('change', function () {
        $('#store_machine').empty();
        switch ($(this).val()) {
            case "1425427806":
                $('#store_machine')
                    .append($('<option value=""></option>'))
                    .append($('<option value="Master">Master</option>'))
                    .append($('<option value="Slave">Slave</option>'));
                break;

            case "1452469394":
                $('#store_machine')
                    .append($('<option value=""></option>'))
                    .append($('<option value="Master">Master</option>'))
                    .append($('<option value="Slave">Slave</option>'));
                break;

            case "1489455419":
                $('#store_machine')
                    .append($('<option value=""></option>'))
                    .append($('<option value="Master">Master</option>'))
                    .append($('<option value="Slave">Slave</option>'));
                break;

            case "1415643163":
                $('#store_machine')
                    .append($('<option value=""></option>'))
                    .append($('<option value="Master">Master</option>'))
                    .append($('<option value="Slave">Slave</option>'));
                break;
            default:
                $('#store_machine')
                    .append($('<option value="">Select Machine</option>'))
                    .append($('<option value="Master">Master</option>'));
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

I need help where am going wrong .Thanks

Comment: please look what you are pasting int he question your code is all buggy with syntax errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many errors in your code. It's hard to list them, so just check the fixed code below. I removed the `readonly` property on the `input` so we can enter data there.

```js
(function() {
  $('#store_id').on('change', function() {
    $('#store_machine').empty();

    switch ($(this).val()) {
      case "1425427806":
        $('#store_machine')
          .append($('<option value=""></option>'))
          .append($('<option value="Master">Master</option>'))
          .append($('<option value="Slave">Slave</option>'));
        break;
      case "1452469394":
        $('#store_machine')
          .append($('<option value=""></option>'))
          .append($('<option value="Master">Master</option>'))
          .append($('<option value="Slave">Slave</option>'));
        break;
      case "1489455419":
        $('#store_machine')
          .append($('<option value=""></option>'))
          .append($('<option value="Master">Master</option>'))
          .append($('<option value="Slave">Slave</option>'));
        break;
      case "1415643163":
        $('#store_machine')
          .append($('<option value=""></option>'))
          .append($('<option value="Master">Master</option>'))
          .append($('<option value="Slave">Slave</option>'));
        break;
      default:
        $('#store_machine')
          .append($('<option value="">Select Machine</option>'))
          .append($('<option value="Master">Master</option>'));
    }
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <b>Store ID</b>
    <br>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="number" id="store_id" />
    <br>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <b>Machine</b>
    <br>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select name="select-native-3" id="store_machine" data-iconpos="left">
            <option value="Master">Master</option> 
            <option value="Slave">Slave</option>
        </select>
    <br>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I don't know why you have all those cases with identical code. Unless that's just a test and you will be changing it to have different code for each case, otherwise you can collapse them altogether and use the same code like this:

```js
(function() {
  $('#store_id').on('change', function() {
    $('#store_machine').empty();

    switch ($(this).val()) {
      case "1425427806":
      case "1452469394":
      case "1489455419":
      case "1415643163":
        $('#store_machine')
          .append($('<option value=""></option>'))
          .append($('<option value="Master">Master</option>'))
          .append($('<option value="Slave">Slave</option>'));
        break;
      default:
        $('#store_machine')
          .append($('<option value="">Select Machine</option>'))
          .append($('<option value="Master">Master</option>'));
    }
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <b>Store ID</b>
    <br>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="number" id="store_id" />
    <br>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <b>Machine</b>
    <br>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select name="select-native-3" id="store_machine" data-iconpos="left">
            <option value="Master">Master</option> 
            <option value="Slave">Slave</option>
        </select>
    <br>
  </td>
</tr>
```